# Using Vue prerender plugin with Vue Router in web hash history mode

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I am trying to solve the problem of SEO being bad on my Vue (SPA) website and am researching the prerender plugins available for Vue 3.

However, it seems that the plugin is unable to read routes that are in WebHashHistory mode as the paths start with '#'.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove # from url by adding   `mode: 'history'` to the vue router

The default mode for vue-router is hash mode - it uses the URL hash to simulate a full URL so that the page won't be reloaded when the URL changes.

To get rid of the hash, we can use the router's history mode, which leverages the history.pushState API to achieve URL navigation without a page reload:

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [...]
})
```

More details [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-history-mode)

Comment: Does the url navigation without page reloading work with vue-router v4's createWebHistory too?

Comment: Very first request will go to the server say '/about' or `/contact` but after that `Vue` will take care of loading pages without reloading

Comment: Alright, I will test it out and come back here if needed. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Uhm now my website does not read my second page. Is there any way around this without configuring the server to solve the 404 error?

Comment: @user16592002 Are you registering your routes correctly? https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes